# flutter using URL launcher plugin does not activate dialer when number tapped

Tags: flutter, dart

if i prefill the string url with a number like "12345678" when tapped it gets directed to phone dialer no problem but when i use "directory.phone" nothing happens even though print log in terminal shows the different numbers i tap.

```
                  InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        String url = 'tel:' + directory.phone;
                        launch(url);
                        print(directory.phone);
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        directory.phone,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12,
                          color: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .bodyText1
                              .color
                              .withAlpha(150),
                        ),
                      ))
                ],
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what numbers you type that give this behaviour?

Comment: not sure if i understand your question fully about an example but basically if i set the url variable like this "url = "tel:1234567"; and then call it with launch(url) when tapped phone dialer is activated with pre-filled number but what i want is to use numbers from my api calls which is why i am using "directory.phone" ...using laravel on backend.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express myself clearly. Can you give an example of what `directory.phone` contains (e.g. the output of your `print` call)?

Comment: i am using card view with phone number shown and when i tap on it i do see in my terminal the different numbers getting outputted:   An Observatory debugger and profiler on iPhone is available at http://127.0.0.1:9107?uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A52348%2FzLXjSXsKnao%3D%2F
flutter: (301) 756-6470
flutter: (301) 523-1484
flutter: (301) 416-5007
flutter: (301) 925-4223

Answer (score 1):

You can check String that returned from API.if it contains spaces remove it.
ex :

```
 String pho=" 555 ".trim();
```

Comment: using the .trim() did not help

Comment: Can you show me output of directory.phone data

Comment: terminal output: An Observatory debugger and profiler on iPhone is available at 127.0.0.1:9107?uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A52348%2FzLXjSXsKnao… flutter: (301) 756-6470 flutter: (301) 523-1484 flutter: (301) 416-5007 flutter: (301) 925-4223

Comment: This format is incorrect and therefore the mobile does not accept an incorrect format (301) 756-6470.change its to 3017566470

Comment: thanks i was able to resolve my issue by using .replaceAll(' ', ''); which removed the middle whitespace from (301) 123-4567 which was the main issue not other special characters, her is my full code:  InkWell(onTap: () {String url = 'tel:' + directory.phone.replaceAll(' ','');
  launch(url);
   print(url);
   },

Answer (score 0):

Update: those that might have the same issue make sure to remove white spaces from the middle of the numbers if any exist which was in my case. (123) 456-7890 is converted to (123)456-7890 allowing Url launcher to work as expected in flutter.

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
   String url = 'tel:' + directory.phone.replaceAll(' ','');
   launch(url);
   print(url);
 },
```